# Responsive issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have a video background with js responsive plugin, but it doesn't work good, i mean there is a black space between

Heres how it looks like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xdyx7p5u7z67fz/Zrzut%20ekranu%202014-03-20%2023.00.25.png

The site

http://xypnise.com/test/

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var video = $("#fs-video");
        var windowObj = $(window);

        function onResizeWindow() {
            resizeVideo(video[0]);
        }

        function onLoadMetaData(e) {
            resizeVideo(e.target);
        }

        function resizeVideo(videoObject) {

            var videoHeight = videoObject.videoHeight * percentWidth / 100;
            video.height(videoHeight);
        }

        video.on("loadedmetadata", onLoadMetaData);
        windowObj.resize(onResizeWindow);
    }
);
```

CSS

```
    #fs-video {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; 
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="cover-video" style="width: 1905px; height: 923px;" >
<video id='fs-video' preload='metadata'  autoplay='true' loop="true" >
    <source src="http://www.xypnise.com/test/clouds_xypnise.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Try adding `max-height: 100%;` to _#fs-video_

Comment: Now, theres even black space on the left and right

Comment: Could of played about on Firefox with Firebox but I guess you have right-click disabled...

Try setting max-width and max-height together; `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;`

Comment: I added max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; but nothing happen, check the site You can see.

Right click is now enable

Comment: Video resolution is 720x404, and it's 3d render so if i have to, i can rerender it with different resolution/ratio

Comment: is your javascript that sets the height video.height(videoHeight);

Comment: try replace video.height(videoHeight); with video.height($(window).height());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aspectRatio = 404/720;
    aspectRatio = aspectRatio.toFixed(3);
    $('#content').css('height', $('body').width() *aspectRatio);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#content').css('height', $('body').width()*aspectRatio);
    });
});
```

Comment: JQUERY DALEK DEMANDS THAT VANILLA.JS USAGE STOP

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to look at a pure css way to do this, check out [this](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) technique.

Just apply a wrapper `<div class="videoWrapper/>` around your video and add the following CSS:

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var aspectRatio=404/720
   document.getElementById('content').style.height=(window.innerWidth*aspectRatio)+'px' 
   document.addEventListener('resize',function() {
     document.getElementById('content').style.height=(window.innerWidth*aspectRatio)+'px'  
   })
 })
```

Comment: This looks like good code, but it is often more useful to readers to have some sort of explanation of what the code is doing, what the original code had wrong, etc. You may want to consider adding that.